# How to add streaming data to the Collection Reader?

Tags: java, twitter4j, uima

I want to add streaming data from the twitter api to my Pipeline and annotate it.

I know how to add static data from the Reader to the Pipeline, but how can i achieve it with streaming data? Is there a way to add external data to the jcas object?

Streaming function:

```
this.twitterStream.addListener(new StatusListener() {
    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        //get data from here to collectionReader
    }

}
```

collection Reader:

```
@Override
public void initialize(UimaContext context) throws ResourceInitializationException{
    super.initialize(context);

}

@Override
public Progress[] getProgress() {
    //return progress of the stream. necessary?
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() throws IOException, CollectionException {
    //return should always be false since the stream has no end
       return false;
}

@Override
public void getNext(JCas jcas) throws IOException, CollectionException {
    //get next element of the stream
}
```

The data should be passed from the API function to the CollectionReader, so i can annotate the data in an Annotator.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you skip the reader and instead create the CASes yourself and pass them to the pipeline.

This is a sample UIMA/uimaFIT Groovy script which doesn't use a reader and instead passes the data directly to a pipeline.

```
@Grab(group='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core', 
      module='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp-asl', 
      version='1.5.0')

import static org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.*;
import static org.apache.uima.fit.util.JCasUtil.*;
import static org.apache.uima.fit.factory.AnalysisEngineFactory.*;
import org.apache.uima.fit.factory.JCasFactory;

import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.*;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.*;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax.type.*;

def jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
jcas.documentText = "This is a test";
jcas.documentLanguage = "en";

runPipeline(jcas,
  createEngineDescription(OpenNlpSegmenter),
  createEngineDescription(OpenNlpPosTagger),
  createEngineDescription(OpenNlpParser,
    OpenNlpParser.PARAM_WRITE_PENN_TREE, true));

select(jcas, Token).each { println "${it.coveredText} ${it.pos.posValue}" }

select(jcas, PennTree).each { println it.pennTree }
```

Note: this script is not at all optimized for performance. In a production scenario, you'd use a pool of CASes (because creating a CAS is kind of expensive and normally they are reused) and you'd instantiate the pipeline using `createEngine(...)` before passing it to `runPipeline(...)` or calling `process(...)` on it because otherwise you'd get a lot of overhead instantiating all the pipeline components for every document.

Source: https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/groovy/recipes/opennlp-postag-no-reader/